# Nav Bar displaying under notification bar

Tags: android

I'm using the default nav bar project edited, so the navbar is oon home.xml and I edited the Main javascript file:

```
package com.invy55.quadernoelettronico;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uname = prefs.getString("username","");
        String pwd = prefs.getString("password","");
        EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        username.setText(uname);
        EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        password.setText(pwd);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public void blogin(View v) {
        EditText unameet = findViewById(R.id.username);
        String username      =  unameet.getText().toString();
        EditText passw = findViewById(R.id.password);
        String password      =  passw.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putString("password", password);
        editor.apply();
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }
}
```

All works fine, but when I start the app and get to the home.xml page trought the login button (as you can see in the code up here), the bar displays buggy:

[image: BUg]

But if then in the menu I press a button like home (which is the current page), it fixes without any problem.

PS: When I click the button Home in the menu it runs this script:

```
package com.invy55.quadernoelettronico.ui.home;

import ...

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've removed `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from home.xml and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fitsSystemWindows` is applied depth first — ordering matters: it’s the first View that consumes the insets that makes a difference. Just plug next to your `Layout`/`Toolbar` in the xml.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: I've putted this string, but the bar is still bugged:
https://i.imgur.com/7dp5MMM.png EDIT: the menu is not visible anymore now EDIT2: this string was already in the nav view include in home.xml

Comment: @MarcoSollo Add above line to your main xml layouts and toolbar. It will solve the problem.

Comment: I've putted it everywhere, but still doesn't work perfectly.